# Android ADB - failed to connect to '192.168.1.4:5037': Connection refused

Tags: android, adb

When I try to connect my mobile device using `adb connect 192.168.1.4:5037` i get `failed to connect to '192.168.1.4:5037': Connection refused` error sometimes.

How can I fix this? This issue happens intermittently. What is the reason behind this & how to fix it?

I even tried killing and restarting adb server

**My steps**

```
adb tcpip 5555
adb connect 192.168.1.4:5555
```

**Additional Info**

1. Device - Poco F1
2. Android - 10

Comment: You did not provide enough details to help you. What model is your device and what version of Android is it running? How is your WiFi network set up? Also, why is the port number in the question title different then in the example? Did you try pinging the mobile device? 'Connection refused' usually indicates the port on the device is closed, but there is not enough information in your question to tell why this happens.

Comment: @LevM. "Port on the device is closed"? how can I check and fix this?

Comment: First tell us why both ports are different in your question. You got `Connection refused` on `5037` port but your steps says port `5555`.

Answer (score 7):

You need to run `adb tcpip 5555` with the USB cable plugged in - and then unplug.

Answer (score 1):

1. `ping 192.168.1.4` to see if this IP is online.
2. `telnet 192.168.1.4 5555` to see if this port is online.

Answer (score 0):

**Try following these instructions:**

1. Open the command prompt and navigate to your sdk/platform-tools/ folder.
2. Type adb `tcpip 5555` with your device plugged in
3. Type adb connect `<your device ip address>:5555`
4. At this point you unplug your device and type `adb logcat`
5. At times, such as unplugging/plugging into a USB device, the `logcat` will become disconnected, just redo steps 3 & 4.

Answer (score 0):

Phone should be connected over USB cable before making connection over Wi-Fi. Once you successfully connected to the device you can unplug the cable.

Just in case, try

```
adb kill-server
```

to restart the server

And make sure developer settings and USB debugging enabled, so it must be working via USB cable

Answer (score 0):

Option I: This might happen when your device keeps changing IP addresses, since WiFi is sometimes switched on and off, and when you get a DHCP lease from your server/Access Point it might change. Keeping your device plugged in via USB (not necessarily to the host, but to any charger), or keeping screen on will ensure it's at the same address, and - assuming that you have the address right and you used adb tcpip (or set the adb TCP property in the shell) it should work.

Option II: You have the port number wrong. "Connection refused" means you got to the IP address, but the port isn't listening. Up there in your question you first state 5037, then 5555?